# Detecting whether someone is speaking in a video

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to figure out how to detect whether a human that I've identified in a video is speaking. I'm using some of the multi-person multi-camera tracking code posted [here](http://cvlab.epfl.ch/research/body/surv) to detect individuals and I want to determine whether someone identified is speaking at any given time. Is anyone aware of good CV projects that might be able to do this? I've trawled around the action recognition literature a bit but haven't found anything that seems to directly address this. Detection of speaking needs to be done only with video.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have mouth tracking and/or head tracking working? Will you be analyzing sound volume and frequency as well?

Answer (score 3):

There is an [implementation](http://blog.dlib.net/2014/08/real-time-face-pose-estimation.html) of face pose estimation in an open source library.

As you can see from this figure : there are lines around lips.By digging into source code of example you can track movement of lips as you try this example on your own environment you will see that lines covering lips are also moving depending on movement of lips.

[image]